# Angularjs with material design Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I have installed angularjs and materialjs using bower.

bower install angular-material

And injected 'ngMaterial' into my app but getting this error.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module demoApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module material.core due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $mdUtilProvider
```

Any Help.

Comment: Are you import the angular-material.js script in the respective index.html?

Comment: yes i have added that in my index.html and also confirmed it.

Comment: You need to show some example code here. What is in your bower,json? It looks like the answer below is likely correct. If so, please accept it.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem until I changed my angular version from 1.2.28 to 1.3.0 in my bower.json file.

See if your angular version is less than 1.3.0, or if you have a dependency which forces angular to a version less than that number.

Hope it helps.

Ps.: I'm using angular-material version 0.7.1

Comment: Yep, it is stated in a few places that Angular 1.3.0+ is required.