# Installing Angular Material, "Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial" even though I'm using angular version 1.3.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

This is very frustrating, Im using a mean.js yeoman generated application and can't get to seem to get angular-material up and running. I read another stackoverflow question about the issue [Angularjs with material design Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587937/angularjs-with-material-design-failed-to-instantiate-module-ngmaterial). So I updated my bower.json file and ran a `bower update` and `bower install`. It still doesnt work. During the bower update, bower gave me this message `Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:`, but I always chose an Angular version 1.3.0 or greater. 
Heres a copy of my bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "colign",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Full-Stack JavaScript with MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~3",
    "angular": "~1.3",
    "angular-resource": "~1.3",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.2",
    "angular-ui-utils": "~0.1.1",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.11",
    "angular-material": "~0.10.0"
  }
}
```

Heres the console error message: 
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngMaterial' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Angular config.js file:

```
'use strict';

// Init the application configuration module for AngularJS application
var ApplicationConfiguration = (function() {
    // Init module configuration options
    var applicationModuleName = 'colign';
    var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'ngMaterial'];

    // Add a new vertical module
    var registerModule = function(moduleName, dependencies) {
        // Create angular module
        angular.module(moduleName, dependencies || []);

        // Add the module to the AngularJS configuration file
        angular.module(applicationModuleName).requires.push(moduleName);
    };

    return {
        applicationModuleName: applicationModuleName,
        applicationModuleVendorDependencies: applicationModuleVendorDependencies,
        registerModule: registerModule
    };
})();
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you includ 'ngMaterial' in your module dependency?

Comment: he certainly did because of the error message!

Comment: Can you provide your html script tags? Maybe you have simply forgotten to add necessary script tags.

Comment: ngMaterial has other dependencies like Angular aria

Comment: Sorry, I didn't register description on bottom. It could be that you miss the angular-aria and angular-animate files like in documentation.

Comment: `var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'ngMaterial'];` does not include `ngAnimate` or `ngAria` as @PSL says in his answer.

Comment: @DavidBarker No, actually that is not what i meant, what i meant was the scripts for them needs to be loaded along with the other scripts.

Comment: @PSL you're right... you didn't... and I didn't read your answer properly :-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Angular material, `ngMaterial`, has dependency on `ngAria` and `ngAnimate` as well. You would need to load them.

```
angular.module('ngMaterial', ["ng","ngAnimate","ngAria", ...other material sub modules
```

You could download it from [angular aria](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-aria.js) and [angular animate](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-animate.js). Use the correct version of these based on your angular version.

Also just adding the scripts in the project is not enough you need to load them in your html as well. Also load them before `ng-material` script.

Comment: Actually you don't need to add dependencies for angular-aria and angular-animate in your bower file as they are dependencies of angular material, and bower will figure it out