# Angular JS Module Injecting Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Recently I have been using angular JS and it is great. However, I do not really understand the injection inside out. I have been using this pattern for almost every page and it works.

```
var workoutApp = angular.module('workoutApp', []);
workoutApp.controller('workoutControllers', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
        //do something with $scope.
```

Now I want to implement auto complete using ngMaterial http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeNqYB

The syntax are totally different from what I have been doing so I am really confused. I tried to inject module this way,

```
var workoutApp = angular.module('workoutApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']);
```

but kept getting error. Can anyone please share some thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, ngMaterial has dependencies on more than just angular.

In the CDN example (https://github.com/angular/material#cdn), you can see the dependencies.

```
<!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.js"></script>
```

It sounds like the fix is as simple as adding these dependencies.

### Related Issues

[Installing Angular Material, "Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial" even though I'm using angular version 1.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032714/installing-angular-material-failed-to-instantiate-module-ngmaterial-even-thou)