# Module 'ngMaterial' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS v1.6.0.

My code:

`var app=   angular.module("appp",["ngMaterial"]);`

The error: `Module 'ngMaterial' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.`

This SO [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032714/installing-angular-material-failed-to-instantiate-module-ngmaterial-even-thou) says to include `ngAria` and `ngAnimate`, which I did:

`var app=   angular.module("charter",["ng","ngAnimate","ngAria","ngMaterial"]);`

Now I get this error:

`Module 'ngAnimate' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.`

In my HTML `<head>` is `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>`.

Do I need more dependencies?

Comment: Normally this error appears when you has not included the scripts in the HTML. Sometimes happen if you put in the scripts angular material before angular itself.

Comment: In my HTML `<head>` is `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>`

Comment: Paste your html in the question ;)

Comment: Yes, you need include angular material dependencies too! Check this codepen: http://codepen.io/team/AngularMaterial/pen/RrbXyW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss include the scripts to angular material.
From official Angular Material Codepen

```
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak>
  <!--
    Your HTML content here
  -->  

  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
  <script type="text/javascript">    
    /**
     * You must include the dependency on 'ngMaterial' 
     */
    angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);
  </script>

</body>
</html>

<!--
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be in foundin the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/license.
-->
```